# Why are all answers on certain questions community wikis?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

Why is every answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string) (as well as the question itself) a community wiki?

Comment: See [How does a post become a Community Wiki post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: @approxiblue that details the behaviour now not then.

Comment: @MartinSmith It details both. "In the past, questions could be made community wiki by their authors or by certain automatic triggers..."

Comment: @approxiblue - It doesn't give any details on the automatic triggers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the olden days a question (and all answers) got converted to CW if the question reached  30 (undeleted) answers.

I imagine that's what happened here.

All of the answers' edit histories, and that of the question, contain

> Post Made Community Wiki by neuhaus    occurred Jul 29 '13 at 14:07

And that user posted their answer at that time.

Comment: And this no longer happens?

Comment: @Aequitas no. The automatic community wikification was abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [the MSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for "What are “Community Wiki” posts?",

**TL;DR**,

> An answer posted to a community wiki question will also be community wiki.

In this case, the question itself if CW, so are the answers.